# Cannot read property 'show' of undefined (call a modal)

Tags: angular

I had a code in which with just putting this piece of code:

```
(click)="crearProcesoAsociado.show()"  //#crearProcesoAsociado id of my modal
```

my modal was called. Before, I had my code in this way and the modal call works well.

```
<a type="button"  (click)="crearProcesoAsociado.show()" >
  open modal
</a>
<div mdbModal #crearProcesoAsociado="mdbModal" class="modal fade" id="crearProcesoAsociado" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="crearProcesoAsociado" aria-hidden="true" [config]="{backdrop: true, ignoreBackdropClick: false}">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    .
    .
    .
```

But for the maintenance of my code I decided to create a component exclusively for my modal with its respective html.
Then from a component that will be the father, I call the modal component:

```
<modal_procesos></modal_procesos>
```

Now with these changes I do not know why it does not work

**HTML Parent**

```
<a type="button"  (click)="crearProcesoAsociado.show()" >
  open modal
</a>
<modal_procesos ></modal_procesos>
```

**Modal template (son)**

```
<div mdbModal #crearProcesoAsociado="mdbModal" class="modal fade" id="crearProcesoAsociado" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="crearProcesoAsociado" aria-hidden="true" [config]="{backdrop: true, ignoreBackdropClick: false}">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
.
.
.
```

how can I solve it? I am using Angular 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you are referring to the templateRef `crearProcesoAsociado` and calling the show function.

```
#crearProcesoAsociado="mdbModal" <--- this
```

When you moved it to a different component, there is no more `crearProcesoAsociado` in the template to let you access to the `show()` function.

To solve this, you must create a function inside the `modal_procesos` called `show` and use ViewChild to get access to the `crearProcesoAsociado` inside its template to call the `crearProcesoAsociado.show()` from inside the newly created function. Also, you will have to attach a templateRef to `modal_procesos` to call its `show()` method like above.

in **HTML Parent**

```
<a type="button"  (click)="modalProcesos.show()" >
  open modal
</a>
<modal_procesos #modalProcesos ></modal_procesos>
```

in `modal_procesos` component .ts

```
@ViewChild(crearProcesoAsociado) crearProcesoAsociado;

... // other code

public show() {
    this.crearProcesoAsociado.show()
}
```

Comment: it works! how can access to show() function in the parent component?? modalProcesos.show(); works int the HTML of the parent but in the component of the parent, this.modalProcesos.show(); not works.. why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54624879/i-can-call-a-modal-in-contained-in-a-child-component-only-from-the-html-of-the-v

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it doesn't work that way.
If you want to do this, then you have to use viewChild to refer to the child component, then you will have to call the method to open the modal. e.g. using `MDBModalRef`.

So on your parent component, you can use:

```
@ViewChild('crearProcesoAsociado') <YourModalComponentNameHere>

openModal(){ 
  YourModalComponentNameHere.open()
}
```

then on your child, you can have:

```
constructor(private modalRef: MDBModalRef) {}

open(){
  this.modalRef.open();
}
```