# I can call a modal in contained in a child component ONLY from the HTML of the view of the parent, not in the component of the father, why?

Tags: angular

I have a component that in turn has embedded a child component. basically from the parent component I call a modal that is contained in the child component. and this works perfectly with a click from the father's HTML.:

```html
<a type="button"  (click)="modal.show()" >
```

**in HTML Parent**

```html
<a type="button"  (click)="modal.show()">
  open modal
</a>
<son #modal ></son>
```

In **HTML son**

```html
<div mdbModal #mymodal="mdbModal" class="modal fade" id="mymodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="mymodal" aria-hidden="true" [config]="{backdrop: true, ignoreBackdropClick: false}">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        .
        .
        .
```

In **son component .ts**

```js
var1:any;
var2:any;
var3:any;
@ViewChild(mymodal) mymodal;

... // other code

public show() {
    this.mymodal.show(); //call a modal
}
```

but this does not work if I call it directly from the component. I would also like to modify the value of the variables that I have defined in the child component, from the parent component and vice versa.

In **PARENT COMPONENT**

```js
@ViewChild('mymodal') mymodal: any;

.
.
ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
  this.mymodal.show(); // Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
  this.mymodal.var1=1;
  this.mymodal.var2=2;
  this.mymodal.var3=3;

  }, 5000)
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: You are calling the child modal even before the views are created and also the modal is will be not available in DOM while parent ngOnInit is called

Comment: @Sreemat I also put it in other functions, not only in the ngOnInit and the same thing happens

Comment: Try creating ViewChild instance with the type of MDBModalRef and try to access it. Also, the timeout is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You referenced a wrong variable in parent component.

First, you need to reference a template variable of `son` component which is `modal`.

```ts
@ViewChild('modal') modal: any;
```

And then, reference a `mymodal` property of `modal` in **parent component**.

```ts
ngOnInit(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.modal.mymodal.show();
    this.modal.var1=1;
    this.modal.var2=2;
    this.modal.var3=3;
  },5000)
}
```